# Changed MySQL fieldtype from TEXT to FLOAT - did I lose all my data?

Tags: mysql

Question says all really...

I have table in a MySQL database which has a field "content". It had lots of entries. The "content" field contained text.

I changed the field type to FLOAT. Now all "content" fields say "0". Oops.

Is there a way to get the data (text) back...?

Comment: Uh oh. I don't think there is. You can try to change it back but I don't think it'll help... As a first step though, make a copy of your data directory in case somebody knows a way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you had a dump of the database from before the change, no, it's gone. Next time, make backups before fiddling with table structures/field definitions.

Comment: Thanks. Now I'm going to sit in a corner and cry. Haha. Note to self: make backups.

Comment: As a vague outside chance, if you have a binary log, you MAY be able to replay the log up until the point that you did the alteration, but most likely the log wouldn't have the entirety of the db's changes in it and you'll end up with an even more munged db.